# Where to get started with using the Wiimote library and C#?

Tags: c#, wii, wiimote

Can someone direct me to resources which will guide me through using C# and the Wiimote library.  [Brian Peek's turorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20110110033048/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/coding4fun/archive/2007/03/14/1879033.aspx) is far too complex for me. I would ideally like to write a program to get the accelerometer values from the wiimote and print it to the console. I am new to C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn from one of the first:

http://johnnylee.net/projects/wii/

Comment: I saw this guy's stuff as well. It doesn't really teach you how to do it. The source still too complicated for me. I am new to C#.

Comment: @Omar - if you're new to C# it might be worth doing a few tutorials first, just to get a good grounding in the language first before starting on the wiimote stuff.

Comment: @ChrisF - Do you think the tutorials provided by Microsoft are enough? http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd492171(VS.100).aspx

Comment: @Omar - I haven't looked at them, but I would guess they're as good a place to start as any.